# Using Emmet with Zurb Foundation Class selectors

Tags: zurb-foundation, emmet

I'm using Foundation Zurbs class selectors for using building a page in HTML. I am using Emmet/Zen Coding for building the page and cannot figure out how to use the Emmet Shortcuts for class selectors that have spaces in them.

So to clarify  the Emmet shortcode below:

```
div.large-4*3
```

produces the code

```
<div class="large-4"></div>
<div class="large-4"></div>
<div class="large-4"></div>
```

However, the Zurb class selectors have a space " " in them of the order of

```
"large-4 columns"
```

if i try to use this class selector in the shortcode syntax as below

```
div.large-4 columns*3
```

it produces the following html

```
div.large-4 <columns></columns>
<columns></columns>
<columns></columns>
```

How do i write the Emmet Shortcode that produces:

```
<div class="large-4 columns"></div>
<div class="large-4 columns"></div>
<div class="large-4 columns"></div>
```

Regards

K*

Comment: `large-4` and `columns` are separate CSS classes. In HTML source they are space-separated, but CSS source for multiple classes does not work like that. Have you tried `div.large-4.columns*3`?

Comment: Ah of course @Neil - you're totally right - I couldn't see the wood for the trees there. Too caught up with trying to understand Foundation than understanding what I was doing!

Comment: I have, of course worked out a more succinct way `.large-4.columns*3`

Comment: Glad I could help. I converted my comment into an answer so that you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

`large-4` and `columns` are separate CSS classes. In the HTML `class` attribute you specify them in a space-separated list but in CSS you simply concatenate the selectors e.g. the CSS selector for `<div class="large-4 columns">` would be `div.large-4.columns`. Assuming that this shortcode takes a CSS selector and generates the equivalent HTML you would then just need the `*3` on the end.